# How many cookies can I set throught a single domain?

Tags: php, cookies

Is there some limit ? or can I set 100000000 cookies throught a single domain ?

Comment: That's a lot of cookies.

Comment: depends on the jar actually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limits vary from browser to browser, and version to version
[This page](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/16/browser-cookie-limits/) gives some idea of the different limits implemented

Answer (score 3):

According to [RFC 2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) section 5.3, the minimum limit is 20.

Comment: That's the **prescribed** limit. But what's the *actual* limit in the different browsers?

Comment: Do you write a different version of your website for every browser?

Comment: Nope, cater for the maximum by knowing the lowest number.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, IE supports [50 cookies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941495) per domain.